# SpringCloudStream - Slow Consumer for RabbitMQ binder

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have a usecase to send http POST to a HTTP Source created as Spring Boot APP with http Source of Spring Cloud Stream App Starter. This process in publishing 5k records/sec. I have a Sink Application to persist the data to Mongo DB. Read in the app is very slow of 20 msgs/sec. I am using the following properties and see no difference. I am using the same prefix to load properties - spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder. Can you please let me know how to achieve concurrency in the read of data from RabbitMQ binder?

**application.properties**

```
spring.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.default.prefix=z.
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=http-source
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.durableSubscription=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=default
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.addresses=localhost:5672
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.username=guest
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.password=guest
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.listener.concurrency=100
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.listener.max-concurrency=500
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.listener.prefetch=1000
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.listener.acknowledge-mode=NONE

server.port=${listen.port}

####################################################
# Mongo
#      Configuration - DEV
####################################################
mongodbDatabasename=*****
mongodbPassword=*****
mongodbUsername=*****
mongodbReplicaName=
mongodbAddresses=localhost:27017
mongodbAuthenticationDatabase=users
mongodbAuthMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1
region=DEV
collectionName=*****
mongodbSocketTimeout=25000
mongodbConnectionTimeout=5000
maxConnectionForHost=5
minConnectionForHost=100
```

Thanks and Appreciate your help
Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to set the concurrency and other consumer related properties as per-binding consumer properties (with the prefix: `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.`. You can refer more detail [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties)

Not sure how did you come up with the properties with the prefix `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.binder.listener.concurrency`. Do you see this anywhere in the documentation?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendaton; listener is derivative/residue from SpringBoot RabbitMQ documentation.

Comment: Works concurrently. How does these two properties impact, do they work on the same queue for the above mentioned destination and group?spring.cloud.stream.instanceCount=3
spring.cloud.stream.instanceIndex=${instance.index}
I pass instance.index as a CMD line argument.

Comment: Hi, the properties `instanceCount` and `instanceIndex` are only used in case of `partitioning` where each queue at the Rabbit binder corresponds to a specific partitioned consumer with the suffix as `instanceIndex` and the `instanceCount` corresponds to how many number of instances of this app are deployed. The `instanceCount` mostly at the deployer level.

Comment: Thank You and Appreciate your time